# Updating the attribute table of feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, editing

The following code updates the value of the field (`"name"`) in the console and shows the result but the actual attribute table does not get updated. Can anybody suggest the error in the code?

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_feature = layer.selectedFeatures()

layer.startEditing()

for feature in selected_feature:
    feature["name"] = "Test name"

layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update the layer with the new feature values using:

```py
layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

So it should look something like:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_feature = layer.selectedFeatures()
layer.startEditing()

for feature in selected_feature:
    feature["name"] = "Test name"
    layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.commitChanges()
```

---

Or shorten it slightly by editing and committing the changes in one go using `with edit()`:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected_feature = layer.selectedFeatures()

with edit(layer):
    for feature in selected_feature:
        feature["name"] = "Test name"
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Comment: @BipinThapaliya - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Comment: Not working for me .Tried both of these versions. I am exhausted ;(

Comment: @ChetanVashisth - Post a question with what you tried and hopefully people will respond :)

Comment: I have just tried your code above and its not working and i just want to update a field in the attribute table. So i thought i do not have to ask a question for that..
:)

Comment: I'm getting a NameError 'edit' is not defined...

Answer (score -1):

`QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()` worked for me on QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Worked for me on QGIS 3.10

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A good answer should include details about how to use your suggestion and info about what it does.  Please [edit] your answer to add additional info.