# Error Updating the Attributes value

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, vector-layer

The code below is not working: This code doesn't affect the table at all

```
layer = point_layer3
selected_feature = layer.selectedFeatures()
print(len(selected_feature))
layer.startEditing()

for feature in selected_feature:
    a = f['parkeer_approx']

    b = parking_capacity[f.id()-int(1)]['parking_capacity']
    feature["parkeer_approx"] = a - b
    layer.updateFeature(feature)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the attribute table of feature using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316958/how-to-update-the-attribute-table-of-feature-using-pyqgis)

Comment: Do you get an actual python error or the code just doesn't update the attribute values?

Comment: What errors do you recieve when you run it? I'm pretty sure it should be `a = feature['parkeer_approx']`. What are you trying to calculate with `b`?

Comment: a and b are the no of parkings actually where a is total parkings and b is alloted parking for that specific id so i want the total - alloted to be updated in the table

Comment: You got it right @vagvaf there is no actual python error but the code seems not to be working

Comment: I found the issue guys. The laye which i was using is not allowed to be edited so that's the reason why i wasn't able to update that layer. So thanks for the response guys .... later....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to what @Joseph pointed out in the comments, in the lines where you set a and b did you mean to use "f" instead of "feature"? Try the updates below:

```py
for feature in selected_feature:
    a = feature['parkeer_approx']

    b = parking_capacity[feature.id()-int(1)]['parking_capacity']
    feature["parkeer_approx"] = a - b
    layer.updateFeature(feature)
```