# Updating attribute table using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I'm tring to update the attributes of a field based on the attributes of another field as follows:

```py
def vulProcessing(layer):
    layerV=QgsVectorLayer(layer,'','ogr')
    layerV.startEditing()
    for feature in layerV.getFeatures():
        if feature['Old'] == "H":
            feature['New'] = 'ddw'
    layerV.updateFeature(feature)
    layerV.commitChanges()
```

The code runs without error but the attribute table does not update.

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/316958/49538

Comment: Probably you just need to put the `updateFeature` call inside your loop. The answer in the question @Fran Raga linked to above should help.